# Window/Document reference from jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 functions like below:

In popup window:

```
 function caller(){
    window.opener.myfunc($('.TestDiv'));
 }
```

In opener:

```
 function myfunc(element){
    alert(element.parents('html').html());
 }
```

The above gives me access to the html root element within myfunc.

How do I get access to the window or document object from the passed in element?

Note: it must be from the passed in element as this may be coming from a different context to that in which myfunc is running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain the document node that contains the selected element with the [`ownerDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.ownerDocument) property of the element node.

```
function myfunc(element) {
    element[0].ownerDocument;
}
```

`[0]` gets the native DOM element; `ownerDocument` gets the ancestor document node.